# How to truncate boost log format expression

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

In general, how can I perform string manipulation on boost log format expressions? in particular, how can I to truncate a TimeStamp expression ending in fractional seconds so that milliseconds are logged rather than microseconds?

Given this snippet, how can I log, for example, 13:13:08.440 instead of 13:13:08.440736?

```
logging::add_file_log("xyz.log",
    keywords::format = expr::stream
        << expr::format_date_time<boost::posix_time::ptime>("TimeStamp", "%T.%f")
);
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
<< expr::format_date_time<boost::posix_time::ptime>("TimeStamp", "%T.%.3f")
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm in the same boat.

Comment: Nope. I just live with microseconds.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no such feature built into Boost.Log. What you can do, however, is to write your own formatting function and set it as a formatter to the Boost.Log sink. You can either create a function that will format the whole record (see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial/formatters.html#log.tutorial.formatters.custom_formatting_functions) for example) or just define an `operator<<` for a specific attribute. [Here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/expressions.html#log.detailed.expressions.attr.tags) is an example. Also note that Boost.Log expressions are based on Boost.Phoenix, so using Boost.Phoenix constructs in filters and formatters is also possible. For example:

```
std::string my_formatter(logging::value_ref< boost::posix_time::ptime > const& timestamp)
{
    if (timestamp)
    {
        // Format date/time here and return the result.
    }
    else
    {
        // The "TimeStamp" attribute value was not found or has unexpected type.
        // Return a placeholder string.
    }
}

logging::add_file_log("xyz.log",
    keywords::format = expr::stream
        << boost::phoenix::bind(&my_formatter, expr::attr<boost::posix_time::ptime>("TimeStamp"))
);
```

Comment: For additional information on building custom formatters, see  [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075854/boost-log-not-showing-custom-timestamp) (and its answer).